# Hangfire Authorize runs multiple times

Tags: c#, hangfire

This code runs every seconds for me:

```
public class CustomAuthorizationFilter : IDashboardAuthorizationFilter {

public bool Authorize(DashboardContext context)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    {
        return true; 
    }

    return false; 
}
}
```

Could you help me why? (I managed to null check HttpContext.Current.User, but this code runs every second)

Answer (score 0):

When you have the dashboard open many Ajax request are made to keep the UI up to date.  These are likely the request you are seeing.  You can inspect the context in the debugger to see the specific route being called.  Also the F12 developer tools in chrome (network tab) will give you some insight as well.